# How to parse XML in Spark with java if columns tags are same name

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I tried parsing XML in spark 2.2 with java 1.8,but this is not giving expected Dataset.

sample xml -

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <RECORD>
             <PROP NAME="product.url">
               <PVAL>url1</PVAL>
                </PROP>
             <PROP NAME="product.id">
                <PVAL>123</PVAL>
              </PROP>
                <PROP NAME="product.language">
                  <PVAL>english</PVAL>
              </PROP>
            </RECORD>
```

Code I have tried -

```
            Dataset<RecordSet> xmlParse = spark
            .read()
            .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
            //.option("rootTag", "RECORDS")
            .option("rowTag", "RECORD")
            .load("sample.xml");

           xmlParse.printSchema()

            root
            |-- PROP: array (nullable = true)
            |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
            |    |    |-- PVAL: string (nullable = true)
            |    |    |-- _NAME: string (nullable = true)
```

xmlParse.show

```
            |PROP                                                                  
             +-------------------------------------------
            |[[urlvalue,product.url],[123,product.id],[English,product.language]] |
```

Expected Dataset/Dataframe : -

```
        product.url|product.id|product.language
        urlvalue   |123       |English
```

Comment: Please don't ask duplicate question. Instead [edit] existing one, to add details.

Comment: Thanks:). Still did not get any answer for new/old one. Can you please help me.Thanks.